# C# SQL Top as parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Trying to parameterize the value of TOP in my sql statement.

```
SELECT TOP @topparam * from table1

command.Parameters.Add("@topparam",SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = somevalue.ToString();
```

This doesn't seem to work. Anyone have any suggestions?
Just to clarify, I don't want to use stored procedures.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

In [SQL Server 2005 and above](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520123828/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html), you can do this:

```
SELECT TOP (@topparam) * from table1
```

Comment: This led me to my answer. I was passing value in as varchar, switching to int fixed it. Thanks all.

Comment: Is there a way to set @topparam to a value that means that it ignores the TOP and returns all rows?

Comment: @SimonGreen That is not possible in MS SQL, since it defeats the purpose of using TOP. You can write this c# code: var topParam = topArg != null ? "TOP(@topparam)" : ""; var qry = $"SELECT {topParam}..."

Answer (score 10):

You need to have at least SQL Server 2005.  This code works fine in 2005/8 for example ...

```
DECLARE @iNum INT
SET @iNum = 10
SELECT TOP (@iNum) TableColumnID
FROM TableName
```

If you have SQL Server 2000, give this a try ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TopNRecords
@intTop INTEGER
AS
SET ROWCOUNT @intTop

SELECT * FROM SomeTable

SET ROWCOUNT 0
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an inline query:

EXEC 'SELECT TOP ' + @topparam + ' * FROM ... '

Parse it as an int and that will prevent a SQL injection attack.