# sqlalchemy execute sql with TOP parametrized

Tags: sql, parameters, sqlalchemy, limit, execute

I want to use limit in mssql, which is TOP, parametrized.
I hoped I can get top parametrized like that:

```
engine.execute( text("select top :t * from Orders), t=100)
```

but I get: Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180) (SQLExecDirectW)') 'select top ? * from Orders' (100,)

With top fixed or out it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1275392/274466), assuming you are using at least SQL Server 2005, you should be able to run:

```
engine.execute(text('select top (:t) * from Orders'), t=100)
```

SQL Server should accept the parameter as long as it's enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Wish I saw this 4 hours ago. Thank you