# 'Incorrect syntax near '2'.'

Tags: c#, sql, select

Im trying to retrieve no of rows from sql based user input & display in gridview

Please help!

```
Int32 text = Convert.ToInt32(this.Txtusers.Text);
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("select TOP '" + text + "' * from Avaya_Id where LOB = '" + DDLOB.SelectedItem.Value + "' and Status = 'Unassigned'", con);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Print `cmd` out and include it in the question.

Comment: `SELECT TOP '2' ...`  should be `SELECT TOP 2 ...` (without the quotes)

Comment: Closing as typo

Comment: 1. `TOP` requires a number, but you set `text` in single quotes. 2. Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com). Please use parameterized queries instead of putting user input directly into your query string!

Comment: If you're using [tag:sql-server], you can parameterize the argument to `TOP` as shown in [C# SQL Top as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1275381/3744182) and [Dynamic SELECT TOP @var In SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/175962/3744182).  See also [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/3744182) for why parameterized SQL queries should always be used instead of directly constructed queries using user input.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how it should be written.

```
int text;
if(int.TryParse(this.Txtusers.Text, out text)
{
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    {
        using(var cmd  = new SqlCommand("select TOP (@top) * from Avaya_Id where LOB = @LOB and Status = 'Unassigned'", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@top", SqlDbType.Int).Value = text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LOB", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DDLOB.SelectedItem.Value;
            con.Open();
            using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Points of interest:

- Using parameters to avoid the risk of Sql Injection.
- Changed `Convert.ToInt32` to `int.TryParse`. Never trust user input.
- Use the `using` statement for every instance that implements the `IDisposable` interface.
- Please note that using `top x` without an `order by` clause means you get x arbitrary records from the database - since database tables are unordered by nature and the only way to ensure the order of the rows returned from a `select` statement is to use the `order by` clause.

Please note I've guessed that the second parameter is an int, if it's not, change the data type.